# How to send notification from user to user in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

[image]so I want to push notifications from device to device and I'm using firebase cloud functions for that and of course node.js as I was searching I found out that there is a new method to retrieve id from firebase firestore but no one explained it in a good way anyway here is the node.js index.js that I'm getting this following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pharmacien_id' of undefined
at exports.sendCommandes.functions.firestore.document.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:8:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:710:26
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

and here is the index.js:

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin=require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendCommandes=functions.firestore.document("Pharmaciens/{pharmacien_id}
   /Commandes/{commande_id}").onWrite(event =>{
  const pharmacien_id=event.params.pharmacien_id;
  const commande_id=event.params.commande_id;
  console.log("pharmacien_id: "+pharmacien_id+" |commande_id: "+commande_id);
});
```

Comment: Notification user to user --> Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: I know it , but my problem is that I can't even log the id of pharmacists in the first place I think the problem is in keyword event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
change event with (change,context) and event.params.uid with context.params.uid